# How does IIS recognize that request is for MVC Controllers or webforms Pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms

When the Application pool receives a request, it simply passes the request to worker process (w3wp.exe) . The worker process “w3wp.exe” looks up the URL of the request in order to load the correct ISAPI extension. ISAPI extensions are the IIS way to handle requests for different resources. Once ASP.NET is installed, it installs its own ISAPI extension (aspnet_isapi.dll) and adds the mapping into IIS.

Si If that's true, my question is how does it recognize which extensions to be loaded
for that request?? MVC / Web Forms?

When and where does the IIS come to know that a request is for MVC or WebForms Application?
How framework decide which Modules should handle the request and decide to render page content or views in MVC.

Answer (score 2):

> hen and were the IIS come to know that request is for MVC or WebForms Application?

They are both ASP.NET applications so it doesn't need to recognize that. The `aspnet_isapi.dll` is perfectly capable of serving both types of applications (which are actually a single type called ASP.NET).

ASP.NET MVC is just a custom handler added to the ASP.NET pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

That all is about the standard IHttpModule and IHttpHandler infrastructure. See complete description here [Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) and here [How ASP.NET MVC Routing Works and its Impact on the Performance of Static Requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx)